# What is the match --mark field in Iptables

Tags: iptables

In the below example

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --syn -m mark  --mark 0x3 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

What is the significance of `-m mark --mark` field?

When I am trying to add this rule I am getting following error.

```
iptables: Protocol wrong type for socket ?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have upgraded my kernel from version 2.6.24 to version 2.6.32, but my iptables was not upgraded they stays at 1.3.6. If I wanted to use MARK the error message "iptables: Protocol wrong type for socket" appeared. After upgrading iptables to version 1.4.8 everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Mark match is used by netfilter to match packets that were marked in the mangle table.Not knowing the specifics I would guess either your kernel is very out of date/you kernel compile errors or your netfilter package might need a look at.

-iptables man page -

mark
       This module matches the netfilter mark field associated with a packet (which can be set using the MARK target below).

```
   [!] --mark value[/mask]
          Matches packets with the given unsigned mark value (if a mask is specified, this is logically ANDed with the mask before the comparison).
```